# Error linking library `libusb`

Tags: macos, homebrew, big-sur, apple-silicon

For some reason, while CMake is able to find `libusb-1.0` (from `pkgconfig`) and correctly identify its linked location, the linker is not able to find the library (*i.e.*, I receive the error `ld: library not found for -lusb-1.0`.)

Some details:

- I am using an M1 Mac
- `libusb` was installed using Homebrew and `brew link` reports it has been linked
- This comes from trying to compile osmocom's `rtl-sdr` library found [here](https://github.com/osmocom/rtl-sdr) (essentially cloning, making a new `build/` directory in the cloned repo folder, and running `cmake ../` from this new directory)
- similar things have failed in previous compilation attempts with other packages

It is very possible I'm being silly and there is an additional step that needs to be taken when attempting to link against these libraries on Big Sur? I'm honestly not 100% sure here.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: I was able to fix the error by manually specifying the library location to the linker, but it feels like there should be a simpler way to go about this? I'm leaving it up as I'm still interested in a more general solution :)

Answer (score -1):

Issue the command:

```
autoreconf -i -I/opt/homebrew/share/aclocal
```

Ticket to update wiki: https://osmocom.org/issues/6012

Comment: That is building a library with autotools - however this library is being built with CMake

Comment: There are instructions on https://osmocom.org/projects/rtl-sdr/wiki/Rtl-sdr how to build using either cmake or autotools......neither of these documented instructions worked on my macos.

I was able to figure out how to build using autotools.

Comment: I think you need to put that in the answer